# Cannot create folder during save or move of file in Office 365, when autosave on OneDrive is enabled

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365, onedrive, files-folders, autosave

Is there a way to create a folder without having to navigate to explorer? If the answer is no then one day maybe MS will make this work how it should work, in which case hopefully it will be intuitive. If the answer is yes it can be done withint Office 365, then please advise because I cannot see it. Maybe there is a setting I can turn on?

In this picture I am moving the file location from the default, because when turning on Autosave within excel it saves directly to OneDrive documents folder, and does not prompt for a different location. Nor does it offer a folder add after the fact, which is the situation I am asking about right now. If the answer is during save then I would love to here about it. Maybe I should not be using Autosave. But Autosave is so prominant that it seems like the intuitive path. Microsoft????

In this pic I have selected the "Saved" down arrow at the top and this "Choose Location" Box opens, it does not have a new folder option. enter image description here
[image]

Comment: why do people down vote and not provide +ve/-ve feedback.
probably the unsavory person that sent me here from StackOverflow.

Comment: Unsavory person? You are quick to make assumptions that benefit you! This question is clearly not within the intended scope of questions on Stack Overflow, and the person who sent you here was doing the right thing in doing so. You don't go to a baking forum to ask how to repair your car's fuel tank, and it would not be an unsavory person who told you so. I would guess that the downvote is for the opinion sprinkled throughout your question about whether Microsoft devs had thought about something, when the answer clearly indicates they had, and it was your own assumptions that were incorrect.

Comment: I upvoted your answer even though it was incorrect. Oh well.

Answer (score 2):

This is the default behavior of AutoSave when you have created a NEW file and instead of saving it first, you hit the AutoSave switch.

If you click Save or Save As, or the Save button in the mini toolbar, or literally any other Save button in the Office UI first, you get to select the location you'll save the file to, AND after you've saved it, you'll find that AutoSave is turned on.

So, clicking the AutoSave function is the fast way to just save a file into the most likely folder (Document) with minimal fuss or effort, but if you want to choose an alternate location, just click any of the other Save buttons in the Office UI first.

Comment: good answer. --- 
it got me a better solution to saving. thank you +1  ---  

however it did not turn on the autosave, I still had to select autosave. Which is fine.  ---  
Now my file is in the correct folder. Great what if I want to move the file now.  ---  
I can move it directly in onedrive, but still no "New Folder" capability.  ---  

so problem still exists.  ---  
I suppose the answer is microsoft never thought of that feature when building a save/move dialogue box (sarcasm intended)